# Can the word “win” be used sarcastically either as a verb or as a noun?

Tags: word-usage, sarcasm

I searched in [The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/win) for win’s definitions to see it’s usage but I couldn’t figure out whether it can be used sarcastically with a negative connotation or not.

Ex:

> Can I say, “I won lots of down votes”?

Comment: it can be used sarcastically, for sure (your example makes lots of sense.) I can't quite figure out what you mean by "pejoratively."

Comment: @hunter, just wanted to say with a negative connotation but maybe pejorative is not the appropriate word.

Comment: Virtually, any words can be used ironically. I guess I prefer saying ironically to sarcastically here; however, it would depend on the speaker's intention. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Verbal_irony_and_sarcasm.

Comment: @DamkerngT., It’s still arguably as said in the link you provided. Thank you, it's a good link indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Sarcasm is essentially saying the opposite of what you mean, but in a certain tone which reveals your true feelings. There's no reason you can't employ *win* in this fashion. *Winning something* has positive *polarity* (*no* or *not* doesn't appear in the sentence) but it doesn't entail positive *emotions* (the result might make you feel bad).

Your example *I won lots of downvotes* does just that. You've "won" (*been awarded* or *successfully acquired*) something you don't want, so the outcome is undesirable.

You might also use *win* sarcastically to describe a hollow or meaningless victory:

> I heard you won the tournament, great job!
>   Oh yes, I won a crushing victory... because nobody else showed up to compete.

The implication here is that the second person didn't really *win* at all as there was no competition. There's a negative connotation because joining a tournament and winning by default tends to make one quite cranky.

Someone extremely cruel might say *you won!* very sarcastically to someone else finishing in last place or performing exceptionally poorly. Similarly, someone doing something trivial or stupid and acting as if they had made a great accomplishment might receive a dry remark of *congratulations, you win the prize.*

Comment: In the board game _Monopoly_, there is a card that says, [You have won second prize in a beauty contest – Collect $10](http://byebyepie.typepad.com/.a/6a00e54f9367fb883401a51181945f970c-pi). Whenever someone gets that card in our family, someone else will often ask jokingly, "How many contestants were there? Two?"

Answer (score -2):

Good question. The word 'win' can be used in negation **if** the competition or the contest is of **winning something *bad* or *badly*!**

The sentence *I won lots of down votes* is okay **if** the goal was to *win* the downvotes.

*Originally,* the word is used in [a positive way](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/win_1?q=win). However, in some contexts, it's used to mention *getting/gain something* but still in a negative way. [An example:](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/02/29/politics/campaign/29POIN.html)

> Representative Richard A. Gephardt of Missouri spent $18 million in his presidential campaign, which ended after he **won fewer than** 14,000 votes in Iowa. That works out to about $1,300 per vote, which would be enough to buy every voter a chicken, a pot and a full-featured stove.

He won the title of *the worst actor* and constructions the like use *win* in a negative way but ultimately due to the nature of the competition/concept, it's *actually* positive. I daresay, *win* is *always* positive.

A *tongue-in-cheek* remark in the [headlines](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/razzies-will-and-jaden-smith-win-worst-actor-honors/) that uses 'win' but sarcastically:

> **Razzies: Will and Jaden Smith "win" worst actor honors**

Comment: Should we always use quotation marks like in the link you provided to draw attention that it’s used sarcastically or is just a matter of style?

Comment: @LucianSava It's a matter of style and emphasis. Quotes make sarcasm explicit and obvious. Sometimes we want to be more subtle about it. The catch is that sarcasm can be difficult to detect in written English, because it makes heavy use of non-literary components like tone of voice or body language.

Comment: certainly, it's just a matter of style.

Comment: The sentence _I won lots of downvotes_ is okay even if the intent is to **avoid** downvotes. For example: "I decided to schedule the board meeting on Friday afternoon, at 4 PM." Answer: "I'll bet that won you a lot of enemies!" That works, even if the meeting's organizer _wasn't_ trying to lose friends.